# Dishwasher Not draining at the end of the cycle

Tags: dishwasher, resistance

My Samsung dishwasher (DMT400RHS/XAA) stopped draining water about three weeks ago.  The “delicate” status light was blinking.  Apparently, a blinking “delicate” light indicates a clogged drain or a drain motor failure.

I opened up the dishwasher, removed the drain pump and checked the drain pump area and found a hard plastic dishwasher piece sitting in the drain pump impeller.  I checked the motor (externally) and found it to be running.  I also checked the resistance across the motor terminals and found it to be about 20 ohms.  Since there was no debris in the drain pump impeller and since there seemed to be no leak in/around the drain pipe or safety basin, I presumed that it was the motor.  I ordered a new (identical) motor and found out that it, too, had a resistance of about 20 ohms (same as the old motor). BTW, the specification on the motor says 120V, 0.8 amps.  So if this is the case, shouldn’t the motor have a resistance of 150 ohms (120/0.8)?

Questions:

1)  What should be the resistance of my drain-pump motor – 20 ohms as measured or 150 ohms as labeled/calculated?
2)  If the motor is not the problem, what else could be the reason for the drain problem (blinking “delicate” status light)?
3)  Should I try the new motor even though it has the same resistance as the old one?
4)  What should be the resistance of a drain motor for Samsung dishwasher (DMT400RHS/XAA)?

I would appreciate any help related to this issue.

Thanks.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Quit worrying about  resistance and concentrate on voltage and amperage

Comment: have you tried turning on and off the breaker for the dishwasher? sometimes that is the only way to reset the status.  is the drain pipe impaler the food grinder?  what does this hard plastic dishwasher piece look like?

Comment: Once the dishwasher settled down (with "delicate" light still blinking), I powered off the unit and initiated the clean-drain cycle.  It did clean-drain and then went on to its regular cycle.  Now I noticed that it DID wash (saw inlet pipe move) and also noticed that it DID drain garbage disposer).  The it went into the next wash cycle.  And for some strange reason, it stalled and then the "delicate" light (drain problem) started blinking again.  So it seems that the motors seem to be functioning properly.  It seems that it is not able to properly switch to drain-mode after in second cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Possible easy solution: Look near your sink top near faucet for a 2 to 3” projection from counter or through a
sink hole. Projection is usually silver but could be color matched to your sink or faucet. This is a dishwasher drain clean out. Lift off the metallic looking cover. Remove debris found there. Replace cover. Run dishwasher. Problem may be eliminated just that easy. I’m older than dirt, had many homes, this has happened to me maybe 4 times in nearly 60 years of so called adulting.
[image: Dishwasher drain cleanout]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, kudos for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 1):

First step always, check the filter of the dishwasher. If once cleaned the problem hasn't been solved, check the drain hose, if still is not draining. In some models, not all of them, check the drain valve (if it's frozen, then the solenoid valve should be replaced).

The first step is the easiest and fastest one, the last one is not so easy (and includes some electrical knowledge). Believe me, people usually don't know how many times problems are solved (dishwasher, washing machines, water purifiers...) only cleaning filters.